# Getting the list LocalAdmins for a set of Server

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of computers (stored in a database) and I want to find out the localadmins on those computers programmatically so that I can store that information in the database too.

I understand this can be done using powershell. But looking for a way to do the same thing using C#

how do I do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just tried this code on my local computer and it works fine:

```
        string hostName = "myComputer";
        //get machine
        using (DirectoryEntry machine = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + hostName))
        {
            //get local admin group
            using (DirectoryEntry group = machine.Children.Find("Administrators", "Group"))
            {
                //get all members of local admin group
                object members = group.Invoke("Members", null);
                foreach (object member in (IEnumerable)members)
                {
                    //get account name
                    string accountName = new DirectoryEntry(member).Name;
                    //DO SOMETHING...
                }
            }        
        }
```

I can't check it on remote computers until I get back to work but presuming you're running under an account that has permissions on the remote computer I should imagine it will work.

Comment: Thanks David for the response. So, this will give the list of any group member  on the local machine..right?  I'm trying to get the LocalAdmins on a list of remote machines. I want to run this program from my desktop and get the list of localadmins on a list of remote machines in the same domain and   a trusting domain.

Comment: Yes.. This works great.  I just needed to add -- using system.collections.generic  at the top.  

Thank you very much..

Comment: this code doesn't compile for me.   I get an error on the foreach line that says IEnumerable<T> requires 1 arguments

Comment: Hmmm - I've not done .NET for years now but it sounds like you're using the generic `IEnumerable<T>` instead of the old collection. They are different types from (I think) `System.Collections` and `System.Collections.Generic` respectively.